# jquery Autocomplete on dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm working with jQuery UI autocomplete plug-in for my web application.
It works perfectly fine for my existing rows, but doesn't quite work for my dynamically added rows.

Here's my jquery code.

```
$(function ()
{
    var tab = $("#tabs-6");
tab.find("input[name='newContactName']").autocomplete(
{
        source: function(request, response) {
            var cachedRequest = $(this).data("cachedRequest");
            // Previous data is cached, so new data is a subset of this
            if (cachedRequest != null && 
                    cachedRequest.length > 0 && 
                    request.term.indexOf(cachedRequest) >= 0)
            {
                ..some code..
            }
            else
            {
                var input = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    ..some code..
                    success: function(data) 
                    {..some code..
                    }

                }); 

            }
        },
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 500
    }
);

tab.find("input[name='newContactName']").bind('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).prev("input[name='newContactId']").val(ui.item.person_id);
    }); 

/* Customizing the autocomplete suggestions box that pops up.
*/
var input1=$("input[name='newContactName']"); 
input1.each(function (){
$(this).autocomplete("widget").css("height", "10em");
$(this).autocomplete("widget").css("overflow", "auto"); 
$(this).autocomplete("widget").css("width", "210px");
});
```

});

This is the jQuery code for the autocomplete plugin for the existing rows, and for the newly added rows, this is the html I'm trying to insert

```
var html = '<tr>..first 8 td elements.. <td><input type="text" name="newContactName"> </td>'+
        ..some more td elements</tr>';

var newRow = $(html).insertAfter(row); // insert content,where row is my current row
newRow.find("td:nth-child(9) input[name='newContact']").autocomplete();
```

How would I make sure that the autocomplete feature works for my newly added rows as well?

Comment: Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of things that might be wrong.

First, when you add a new row, you set the input's name to "newContactName", yet when you find() you look for "name='newContact'".

Also, when calling the autocomplete() on the results of find(), you'll need to specify the source option.  Since you had source set to a function in your non-dynamic rows, you'll probably want to break that out to a named function and use the named function as the source in both autocomplete() calls.

Hope this helps...